# Julia: How to find roots of equations including numeric integration?

Tags: julia

The equation is shaped like

$\int_a^b f(x,t)dt=0$

How to find the solution x effectively with numerical methods?

I have tried

```
using Cubature
using Roots
g(x) = hquadrature(t -> f(x,t), 0, 1, reltol=1e-8, abstol=0, maxevals=0)[1]
find_zero(g, 0)
```

Suppose that the root is expected near 0. But the program above can't find this root for a period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will (probably) never terminate. If you are looking for a root, that means your integral should have value 0, which means that your relative tolerance is `1e-8` relative to `0`, which is `0`. You also have zero absolute tolerance. The only way for the quadrature to actually terminate is for the error to become *less* than `eps(0.0) = 5.0e-324`.

In other words, you need to set `abstol` to something greater than zero.

Also, your integral is 1-dimensional, so there is no particular need to use cubature, you could use QuadGK.jl or FastGaussQuadrature.jl instead.

Comment: Much appreciate. Does QuadGK support real-variable but complex-valued functions?